# Generate kid for jwt from public key of signing key

Tags: c#, encryption, jwt

Given:

- a signing key generated by RSACryptoServiceProvider.
- a requirement to create a signed jwt with a kid.

If the signing key was from a x509 certificate, then I would set the kid to the x5t. In this case it is not. I could make up something arbitrary for the kid, but it would be best if collisions were unlikely and that there is a meaningful link between the kid and the cert.

What I am intending is: -

1. Create a byte array which is created by appending the modulus bytes to the exponent bytes.
2. SHA256 encode the array.
3. Base64 the SHA256.
4. set kid to base64 string.

Pretty much this:

```
var kid = Base64(SHA256(concat(exp,mod)))
```

Does this seem a valid approach? Is there an easier way to get a thumbprint from `RSASecurityKey`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, the key ID for other protocols consists of a hash (commonly SHA-1) over the modulus. The modulus should be unique for the key pair and therefore the public and private key. It has the advantage that it can be calculated from the private *and* the public key, while being useful to identify either one.

The modulus should be encoded to a big endian, unsigned integer using the minimum amount of bytes.

Comment: Great, thanks. Just a couple of clarifications that you can maybe add to the answer: "key ID for other protocols" - what is meant by "other protocols"? Also, can you reference any docs that describe the approach you have provided (I couldn't find any)? Otherwise, unless there are any developments in the next few hours I will mark this as the accepted answer.

Comment: PKCS#11 commonly uses this. I'd have to check if this is simply common usage or if it has been defined that way... tomorrow.